# Convert a fixed-length line by line text file into SQL and transpose

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, ssms, sql-server-express

I have a very large text file (3gb) of data in a simple list in the format:

```
NEW
2016-08-15_20-45-47-3120
0
0
0
0
1960
0
0
```

Every new data entry is started by "NEW" then followed by the date stamp and 456 numbers.

I'd like to transform it into a format like:

```
New   2016-08-15_20-45-47-3120 0 190 0 300
New   2016-08-15_20-45-47-3140 0 0   0 0
New   2016-08-15_20-45-47-3620 1 34  4 76
```

I'd normally offset it in excel first but with such a large data set it can't begin to cope so it's got to be done in SQL.

Thanks

Comment: these kind of tasks  can be efficiently handled by writing some c# utitlity .once in the format ,you can use bulk import

Comment: Is the structure of the desired record fixed? In other words, do you expect the number of input record after the `new` to be 5?

Comment: Also, what is your OS?

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of thing I find awk useful for.

This script captures every line it sees into an array, which it outputs and resets every time it sees the line containing NEW (or the end of file). If you save this code to `transpose.awk`, it can be run with `awk -f transpose.awk big.txt > out.txt`.

```
function output(a,n,  i)
{
    if(n > 0)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf "%s\t", a[i];
        }
        printf "\n";
    }
}
/^NEW/ { output(a,n); n=0; delete a; }
{ a[n++] = $0; }
END { output(a,n); }
```

If you wanted to only output the first 5 columns instead of all 8, you could change the `for` loop to stop earlier.

I tested this with a 224M dummy sample file and it took 44 seconds on my computer, so 3GB should take roughly ten minutes. Not fast, but bearable.